# Reload module on remote ipengine when using ipython

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython

Hoping this has a straightforward answer that I missed from my reading of the docs. Following is the problem -

1. I have a module loaded on all ipengine(s) on startup
2. I've since made changes to the module
3. I want these changes propagated to the remote ipengine(s) i.e. I want the module to be reloaded in all the remote instances

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer I found, not sure if this is the best way

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
rc = Client(profile='ssh')
dview = rc[:]
dview.execute('reload(<module>)', block = True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also turn on the ipython autoreload feature on the engines with the following:

```
%px %load_ext autoreload
%px %autoreload 2
```

Note that this solution, and calling reload with dview.execute() both have a problem when new engines can come online later (as when using a batch scheduler on a cluster): they only execute on the engines currently present.

One other wrinkle: you may want deep (recursive) reloading.  See this option to ipengine:

```
--ZMQInteractiveShell.deep_reload=<CBool>
Default: False
Enable deep (recursive) reloading by default. IPython can use the
deep_reload module which reloads changes in modules recursively (it replaces
the reload() function, so you don't need to change anything to use it).
deep_reload() forces a full reload of modules whose code may have changed,
which the default reload() function does not.  When deep_reload is off,
IPython will use the normal reload(), but deep_reload will still be
available as dreload().
```

Comment: Does that actually work? I'm using that but nothing gets reloaded nor deep_reloaded

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, where I was working on a module that I wanted to test on remote engines, but I didn't want to commit my changes to git, and then pull the changes on the engine machines before each remote reload.

There might be a better way to do this, but my solution was to write [a simple helper module](https://github.com/ihincks/ishuttle) which makes it easy to shuttle in-progress code over to the engines via scp.

I will copy the usage example here:

```
import IPython.parallel
import ishuttle
import my_module as mm

# Create a client for the cluster with remote engines
rc = IPython.parallel.Client(profile='remote_ssh_engines')
dview = rc[:]

# Create a shuttle object; the engines' working directory
# is switched to '/Remote/engine/server/scratch' after its creation
s = ishuttle.Shuttle(rc, '/Remote/engine/server/scratch')

# Make my_module available on all engines as mm. This code scp's the
# module over, imports it as mm, then reloads it.
s.remote_import('my_module', import_as='mm')

# Apply our favourite function from our favourite module
dview.apply_sync(mm.my_func, 'favourite argument for my_func')
```